# LibreOffice Calc - Delete empty rows

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice Calc and my data sheet contains a couple of empty rows. For example:

[image]

I'd like to know how I can delete all empty rows from the selection. As a workaround I've tried to copy the selection, remove it, then "paste special", tick "Skip empty cells", however this did paste all the empty cells as well.

If there was a way to *select* all empty rows from a given selection then I could simply delete them. However I didn't find a way for that either.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Not in one go, but with a small workaround:

1. Select the whole of your spreadsheet (e.g. by clicking in the empty square to the left of the "A" column header).
2. Turn on Autofilter.
   [image]
3. From the drop down list at the top of a column, select "Empty" in each column until you end up with only empty rows.
4. Select and delete these.
5. Reset the filter.

Your non-empty lines will reappear.

Comment: Small addition for non-familiar with Autofilter (as me) https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Applying_AutoFilter Thank you, it works great. Standard filters with custom expressions helped me a lot.

Comment: I used this the other way : in the autofilters list, i unchecked only 'empty' and copied the  remaining cells in another

Comment: "Turn on Autofilter" is in menu Data > Autofilter, and "Reset the filter" is Data > More Filters > Reset Filter

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround would be to sort the data by a column that you know will contain a value for every single row that contains data.

1. Select column range
2. Data > Sort...

All relevant rows should end up at the top.

Comment: ...though alas in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old right now, but recently an extension has been released that makes it quite easy to remove empty rows and columns in a variety of ways.

It is on Github: https://github.com/rafaelhlima/remove_blank_cells